# Можно ли спрятать импорт-ссылку?

Tags: google-chrome, php

Можно ли спрятать ссылку, которая импортируется от просмотра исходника?
То бишь есть у меня ссылка style.php?чтото=что, которая импортируется

```
@import "?чтото=что" screen;
```

При нажатии в браузере F12 и переходе во вкладку Sources я вижу эту ссылку. Можно ли её спрятать? Интересует любой способ.

[image]

Если в браузере перейти по ссылке сайт/style.php?чтото=что и нажать F12, то всё так, как и хотелось бы мне, файл пуст, но если нажать F12, к примеру, на главной, то он находит этот путь и отображает исходный код файла.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя. Но попробуйте запихнуть перед ней кучу пробелов/переносов строк: распространенный способ "спрятать" исходники сайта от начинающих вебмастеров.
Ненадежен.

Comment: Нет ничего невозможного, как по мне. Должен быть способ. Либо способ сокрытия самого исходного кода :)

Comment: Если код скрыт, то как браузер его исполнит? А если браузер имеет доступ, то и пользователь будет иметь.

Comment: @KoVadim, по сути, при просмотре исходного кода страницы там ничего нет, а вот через консольное меню в браузере он ненарочно определяет ссылку, которая есть в @import, нужно чтобы он не выводил эту ссылку в консольном меню, всё остальное не важно :)
____

@KoVadim, обновил немного вопрос.

Comment: Не хотите, чтобы браузер ее выводил, не отдавайте ее браузеру. Все, что Вы отдали браузеру, пользователь может увидеть.

Comment: @Rnddev

> Нет ничего невозможного как по мне. 

Конечно нет! Вот вам несколько сценариев на выбор:

1. Взломайте все ОС и заставьте их крашится при выводе желаемого сочетания букв, чтобы никто даже в девтулс не мог зайти.
2. Сделайте браузер, который будет скрывать ваши стили, и заставьте им пользоваться 100% аудитории.
3. Купите себе интернет (весь) и устанавливайте свои правила.
4. Сделайте свой сайт настолько неинтересным, чтобы туда никто не заходил.

Comment: Вообще можно запихнуть в js и обфусцировать / получать через аякс, но, судя по изначальной постановке, с обязательным импортом этот метод окажется недостаточно хорошим.